# Devolver matriz en un método java

Tags: java, array, método

Me gustaría saber como hago para devolver los valores de una matriz en un método.Me gustaría mostrar el `array` en el programa principal. Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mistermind {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public static int crear_tabla() {
        int matrizDefecto[]=new int [5];
        for(int i=0;i>matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
            matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);
        }
        return matrizDefecto[?];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

El error de tu código es básicamente que no indicas que el método vaya a devolver un array, si no que que devuelve un valor entero (int). En este caso y con 'return matrizDefecto[x]' te funciona pero te devuelve una única posición de la matriz.

Primero debes cambiar la cabecera del método para que este devuelva una matriz unidimensional en tu caso. Además, en la sentencia return no debes especificar ninguna posición, únicamente el nombre de la matriz, de esta forma devuelves la matriz entera.

El código sería algo así:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class mistermind {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int [] array = crear_tabla();
    }
    //int [] --> indica que el método devuelve una matriz unidimensional de enteros
    public static int[] crear_tabla() {
        int matrizDefecto[]=new int [5];
        for(int i=0;i>matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
            matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);
        }
        //Devuelves la matriz completa (no se especifica ninguna posición)
        return matrizDefecto;
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: tu sugiero que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Tu código no tiene ningún comentario útil. Podrías aclarar mejor tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras.. ya he editado la respuesta para añadir más detalles.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class sizeMatrix {
    
    public int filas ;
    private int columnas;
    private int  matrix[][]  =new int[columnas][filas];
    
    public int[][] SizesMatrix(){
        // entras en el metodo y se pedira el tamaño de la matriz
        columnas  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de columnas"));
        filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero de filas"));       
       
        // se crea una variable local dl metodo para depues guardarla en la matriz local de la clase
        int matrix[][] = new  int[filas][columnas];
       
        // se piden los elemetos de la matriz
        for(int i=0; i < columnas; i++){
        
            for(int j =0; j<filas; j++ ){
            
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el vaor en la posicion+ ["+ (i+1) +"] "+"["+ (j+1)+"]"+ " de la matriz"));
            }
        
        }    
         
        // se guradarda en la variable local de la clase la matriz creada
        this.matrix = matrix;
        
        // te regresa la matriz
        return  matrix ;
   }  
    
                        // te pide una matriz este metodo                      
   public void mostarMatriz(int[][] matrix){
     
       for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
       
         for(int j=0; j<columnas; j++){
           
               System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
               
          }
           System.out.println(" ");
       }
       
       
    
   }
    
    

}
```